# How can daily steps total be queried from Healthkit and displayed into SwiftUI text view?

Tags: swift, watchkit, healthkit

I am trying to get the total number of steps that a user has taken today and display this number of steps into a SwiftUI text view on an Apple Watch screen.

All the code snippets that I'm finding online aren't working. It seems like hkstatisticscollectionquery should be what is used to get this type of data, but the code in Apple documentation isn't working for me. I have already asked the user for permission to read steps data from healthkit so all that needs to be done is to query this data and put into a SwiftUI text view. Below is Apple's developer documentation that contains the code that I can't get to work.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery

Here is the code that Apple supplies to query steps that is not working for me.

```swift
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let interval = NSDateComponents()
interval.day = 7

// Set the anchor date to Monday at 3:00 a.m.
let anchorComponents = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year, .Weekday], fromDate: NSDate())


let offset = (7 + anchorComponents.weekday - 2) % 7
anchorComponents.day -= offset
anchorComponents.hour = 3

guard let anchorDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(anchorComponents) else {
    fatalError("*** unable to create a valid date from the given components ***")
}

guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount) else {
    fatalError("*** Unable to create a step count type ***")
}

// Create the query
let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: quantityType,
                                        quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                        options: .CumulativeSum,
                                        anchorDate: anchorDate,
                                        intervalComponents: interval)

// Set the results handler
query.initialResultsHandler = {
    query, results, error in

    guard let statsCollection = results else {
        // Perform proper error handling here
        fatalError("*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: \(error?.localizedDescription) ***")
    }

    let endDate = NSDate()

    guard let startDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: -3, toDate: endDate, options: []) else {
        fatalError("*** Unable to calculate the start date ***")
    }

    // Plot the weekly step counts over the past 3 months
    statsCollection.enumerateStatisticsFromDate(startDate, toDate: endDate) { [unowned self] statistics, stop in

        if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
            let date = statistics.startDate
            let value = quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())

            // Call a custom method to plot each data point.
            self.plotWeeklyStepCount(value, forDate: date)
        }
    }
}

healthStore.executeQuery(query)
```

How can the total number of steps that a user has taken today be queried from Healthkit and displayed into a SwiftUI text view?

Comment: show some code.

Comment: Okay, I just added code John.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit out of date according to Xcode 11.2 but it runs on my Mac and returns the correct data. Here are my changes to bring it up to date;

```
func stepstest()
{
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let interval = NSDateComponents()
    interval.day = 7

    // Set the anchor date to Monday at 3:00 a.m.
    var anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .weekday], from: Date())


    var offset = (7 + anchorComponents.weekday! - 2) % 7
    anchorComponents.day! -= offset
    anchorComponents.hour = 3
    //comp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: Date())
    //let startOfMonth = Calendar.current.date(from: comp)!

    guard let anchorDate = Calendar.current.date(from: anchorComponents) else {
        fatalError("*** unable to create a valid date from the given components ***")
    }

    guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount) else {
        fatalError("*** Unable to create a step count type ***")
    }

    // Create the query
    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: quantityType,
                                            quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                            options: .cumulativeSum,
                                            anchorDate: anchorDate,
                                            intervalComponents: interval as DateComponents)

    // Set the results handler
    query.initialResultsHandler = {
        query, results, error in

        guard let statsCollection = results else {
            // Perform proper error handling here
            fatalError("*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: \(error?.localizedDescription) ***")
        }

        let endDate = Date()


        guard let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -3, to: endDate) else {
            fatalError("*** Unable to calculate the start date ***")
        }

        // Plot the weekly step counts over the past 3 months
        statsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: endDate) { [unowned self] statistics, stop in

            if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                let date = statistics.startDate
                let value = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())

                // Call a custom method to plot each data point.
                 self.plotWeeklyStepCount(value, forDate: date)
            }
        }
    }

    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

Comment: The code you supplied is still returning error messages for me and won't run. Xcode is telling me that self is an unresolved identifier (on the statscollection line) and Xcode says that healthstore is an unresolved identifier. I imported Healthkit and Foundation into the swift file that I put your code into.

Comment: is HealthKit enabled in your 'signing and capabilities' tab for your project target? Also, you have to define healthStore yourself. in my app I have " let healthStore = HKHealthStore()" in my class definition. You can test the code with out the  [unowned self] in there. Just change it to "{ statistics, stop in"

Comment: Yes Healthkit is enabled in signing and capabilities tab. I defined the healthStore so now that is working. There is only one current problem. I took out the [unowned self] but now the self.plotWeeklyStepcount is returning an error message that says self is an unresolved identifier.

Comment: No I'm not. I just put the code as is into a swift file. How do I run this code as a class?

Comment: self refers to the class that the code is running in. This is why you are getting errors. If the code is not in a class, then self isn't defined. You will have to learn a bit of object oriented programming. it's too a big a topic for this space.

Comment: No need to explain object oriented programming. It would be helpful if you or someone else could modify the code so that everything that needs to be defined is defined. It seems that the code that we both posted isn't the complete solution to this problem.

Comment: is it daily though?